How can I use my own composables inside a playwright test?
I replaced pinia with a custom composable "useSettings". In my playwright tests, I was able to access Pinia like this:
window.__NUXT__?.pinia.myStore

Now when I try to use my composable inside my tests, I am getting the error "useSettings is not defined".
How can I import it? 
The use case is simple:
In order to decide if my app should show a cookie banner, I have a variable "xIpContinent". This used to reside inside a pinia store, and I could access it via playwright.
Now this variable is provided by a composable, which I am not able to use inside my test - and I don't know how to access it.
Update after the comments:
All right, I am with you on the whole framework agnostic testing. However, in my use case requires some additional information.
Depending on the client IP, a cookie banner is shown (or not). In order to test this behaviour, I need to know whether to expect a cookie banner or not. Only my app knows the client IP.
Also, every subsequent test is impacted by the cookie banner which is pretty invasive - as long as it is shown, other buttons cannot be clicked.
Dealing with this without knowing what to expect will definitely increase the complexity of my E2E tests 

Taking a step back, Playwright is an E2E testing library. The philosophy is that you interact with user-visible actions and test your page as a human would. Humans visiting your site do not know what Pinia is or manipulate it directly. It's an implementation detail--manipulate the UI, and if it happens to manage state with Pinia, great, but if you refactor to another state management solution as you've done, your tests should not change. Playwright runs in Node, so don't import window into Node. Long story short: this may be an XY problem, which can be solved by providing context and a [mcve].

You are right. I updated the question.

Thanks. After the update, my comment still applies: you don't want to test this sort of thing with Playwright. Test the UI--click a button, assert that something showed up on the screen! Whether it got there with Vue, React, Angular, SQL, Mongo, Pinia, composables, hooks, or COBOL is totally irrelevant to E2E tests. I still suggest providing more details--what page are you testing and what user-visible behavior are you trying to test?

Test the interface, not the implementation.As that might change underneath in the future but that's not your concern as long it's not affecting user facing behaviour which is the UI.

Don't. Playwright is designed to be framework agnostic and not to test implementation details. You want to test user-visible behavior. The idea is to manipulate the app as your users would, by clicking and typing into the UI and asserting observable text changes, and the presence or absence of elements on the screen. Your users will not examine window variables or open the browser console, so neither should your tests. Your users don't care about variables, composables, stores, CSS classes, XPaths, or JavaScript libraries, and neither should your tests.
Unit tests, not end to end tests, are aware of the UI library being used and the parameters and rendering values returned by components. Unit testing is also aware of state management solutions and will likely mock stores and network calls.
But even in unit tests, local variables, composables and hooks are private to the component and are inaccessible to other components, as well as your tests, and are therefore still implementation details. Don't test them directly--manipulate the component as a user would (either a programmer client, a component passing props, injecting a service, or a human user of the interface, not the test user).
This is no different from testing a vanilla JS service function or utility. You pass in parameters and assert on the return value. All of the local variables that help produce that output are unknown. We don't care how the function (or component, in a UI unit test) does its job, we care only that it does its job correctly. Linters and static analysis tools check variable naming conventions and internal function complexity, not unit tests.
But unit tests are another story--in E2E tests, composables are completely irrelevant and should not be tested, because it makes your tests fragile, tests the wrong layer of abstraction, runs much more slowly than unit tests, and doesn't give any confidence that the application is working for the user. The more "black box" you can write your E2E tests, the less time you'll have to spend fixing broken tests, dealing with flakiness and missing bugs that your users can see.
If you write your tests following Playwright best practices, you should be able to swap state management solutions, or even UI frameworks, without having to change any tests. In practice, it's not always possible, but the extent to which you can embrace that philosophy, the better. If you'd followed these principles from the start, you'd never have had to ask the question here! (But it's never too late to stop testing implementation details, now that you've experienced the problems caused by doing so firsthand).
By the way, don't let coverage concerns make you want to test implementation details. You can measure coverage transitively without knowing the implementation details--clicking a button triggers a callback and state changes, giving you coverage.

Thank you for your concise answer. I updated my question, shedding some light on my particular test.

Without a specific example, I don't see how the cookie banner changes anything. Why not just block the cookie banner element for all tests, except for the one or two where you want to test it? And in those tests, you definitely don't want to test the composable, since that doesn't give you confidence the banner is actually rendered to the user, only that it's in state. You'd probably use something like await expect(page.locator("#cookie-banner")).toBeVisible() (or use a getByRole if possible on some unique button and text in the banner).

You can also dismiss it in a beforeEach test, or cache it having been dismissed in the userDataDir and dismiss it in a setup function that runs before all tests except for the ones where you're directly testing the banner.
